# Foursquare API list from Explore Endpoint but not from Search Endpoint

Tags: python, foursquare

In the Foursquare developer documentation, it mention that by using explore endpoint, the API will return the recommendation or top venues. Such I want to use search endpoint because I do not want top/recommendation list.

With `limit = 100` and radius = `10000`, my explore endpoint as follow;

```
def getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes):    
    venues_list = []

    for name, lat, lng in zip(names, latitudes, longitudes):
        url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}&ll={},{}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(
            client_id, 
            client_secret, 
            ver, 
            lat, 
            lng, 
            radius, 
            limit)

        results = requests.get(url).json()["response"]['groups'][0]['items']
        venues_list.append([(name, 
                             lat, 
                             lng, 
                             v['venue']['name'], 
                             v['venue']['categories'][0]['name'], 
                             v['venue']['location']['lat'], 
                             v['venue']['location']['lng'] 
                            ) for v in results])

    nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for venue_list in venues_list for item in venue_list])
    nearby_venues.columns = ['Area', 
                             'Area_Latitude', 
                             'Area_Longitude', 
                             'Venue', 
                             'Venue_Category', 
                             'Venue_Latitude', 
                             'Venue_Longitude'
                            ]

    return(nearby_venues)
```

In order to use search endpoint I modified the code as following;

```
def getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes):    
    venues_list = []

    for name, lat, lng in zip(names, latitudes, longitudes):
        url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}&ll={},{}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(
            client_id, 
            client_secret, 
            ver, 
            lat, 
            lng, 
            radius, 
            limit)

        results = requests.get(url).json()["response"]['venues']
        venues_list.append([(name, 
                             lat, 
                             lng, 
                             v['name'], 
                             v['categories'][0]['name'], 
                             v['location']['lat'], 
                             v['location']['lng'] 
                            ) for v in results])

    nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for venue_list in venues_list for item in venue_list])
    nearby_venues.columns = ['Area', 
                             'Area_Latitude', 
                             'Area_Longitude', 
                             'Venue', 
                             'Venue_Category', 
                             'Venue_Latitude', 
                             'Venue_Longitude'
                            ]

    return(nearby_venues)
```

It keep giving me error, one of which "string indices must to be integer".

I even check the keys using `result['response']['venue'].keys())` to make sure i using the correct path.

It seem that for search ['response']['venue'][index number] which Im not sure how to loop that...

Is there a workaround this problem or I stuck using explore for this?

Comment: Replace `['response']['venue']` with `['response']['venues']`

Comment: in search endpoint? i already use `['venues']`